# Do you always have to run rake assets:precompile locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I read the docs but can't seem to understand if you have to run rake assets:precompile locally each time you change scss file or any other assets? Isn't there an automatic way to do it? One of the things I have noticed is that I forget to run it sometimes and my heroku changes do not appear. There must be a way to set it up automatically in rails?

If I change

> config.assets.compile = false

to true, will do that it? Is a disadvantage of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to precompile your assets for Heroku to serve them. Heroku will precompile your assets automatically if you have not already precompiled assets locally. Read [this heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) regarding the asset pipeline in Rails 3 (even if you are already using Rails 4). Then read [this doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) regarding the asset pipeline in Rails 4 on heroku.

Pay particular attention to this part:

> If a public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will
>   assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not
>   attempt to compile your assets. Rails 4 uses a file called
>   public/assets/manifest-.json instead. On both versions you
>   can generate this file by running `$ rake assets:precompile` locally and
>   checking the resultant files into Git.

Comment: Heroku will precompile them once but what if you change them again.. I don't think it will attemp to precompile them and just use old precompiled file right?

Comment: It will precompile them if it detects a change. It would be pretty useless otherwise.

Comment: didn't precompile on heroku for me.. I had to manually run rake assets:precompile

Comment: Did you delete your old precompiled assets before pushing to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

rake assets:precompile must be run for production environment. Do not need to run the command for the development environment. The command is used to collect all files into one and so be lighter to serve in production. Under development the styles they are wanted in the assets folder. After running the command, the styles are placed in the public folder.

Comment: Do you have to do it each time or you can auto config it?

Comment: For development is not necessary to run them whenever you make a change. In production, in my experience, if necessary by need precompiled files with the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to run rake assets:precompile Heroku should do it automatically. One reason it may not be is if you have checked your public folder into git as then during slug compilation Heroku will assume you precompiled your assets and will not do it for you.

Setting config.assets.compile = true can slow down your application by a lot, which is why it is only used in development.